# Why are my SQL Query parameters not returning proper vales?

Tags: python, sql, scripting

I'm trying to create an SQL queries for a large list of records (>42 million) to insert into a remote database. Right now I'm building queries in the format `INSERT INTO tablename (columnnames) VALUES (values)`
tablename, columnnames, and values are all of varying length so I'm generating a number of placeholders equal to the number of values required.

The result is I have a string called sqcommand that looks like `INSERT INTO ColName (?,?,?) VALUES (?,?,?);` and a list of parameters that looks like `([Name1, Name2, Name3, Val1, Val2, Val3])`.

When try to execute the query as `db.execute(sqlcommand, params)` I get errors indicating I'm trying to insert into columns "@P1", "@P2", "@P3" et cetera. Why aren't the values from my list properly translating? Where is it getting "@P1" from? I know I don't have a column of that name and as far as I can tell I'm not referencing a column of that name yet the execute method is still trying to use it.

UPDATE: As per request, the full code is below, modified to avoid anything that might be private. The end result of this is to move data, row by row, from an sqlite3 db file to an AWS SQL server.

```
newDB = pyodbc.connect(newDataBase)
oldDB = sqlite3.connect(oldDatabase)

tables = oldDB.execute("SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';").fetchall()
t0 = datetime.now()
for table in tables:
    print('Parsing:', str(table[1]))
    t1 = datetime.now()
    colInfo = oldDB.execute('PRAGMA table_info('+table[1]+');').fetchall()
    cols = list()
    cph = ""
    i = 0
    for col in colInfo:
        cph += "?,"
        cols.append(str(col[1]))
    rowCount = oldDB.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "+table[1]+" ;").fetchall()
    count = 0
    while count <= int(rowCount[0][0]):
        params = list()
        params.append(cols)
        count += 1
        row = oldDB.execute("SELECT * FROM "+table[1]+" LIMIT 1;").fetchone()
        ph = ""
        for val in row:
            ph += "?,"
            params = params.append(str(val))
        ph = ph[:-1]
        cph = cph[:-1]
        print(str(table[1]))
        sqlcommand = "INSERT INTO "+str(table[1])+" ("+cph+") VALUES ("+ph+");"
        print(sqlcommand)
        print(params)
        newDB.execute(sqlcommand, params)
        sqlcommand = "DELETE FROM ? WHERE ? = ?;"
        oldDB.execute(sqlcommand, (str(table[1]), cols[0], vals[0],))
        newDB.commit()
```

Comment: Can you post the code please

Comment: You *CAN'T* pass column or table names as parameters. Parameters are for values

Answer (score 0):

Unbeknownst to me, column names can't be passed as parameters.  Panagiotis Kanavos answered this in a comment. I guess I'll have to figure out a different way to generate the queries. Thank you all very much, I appreciate it.